# How do you find all available abbrevs in elisp?

Tags: emacs

For kinda goofy reasons I want to write a completing-read function to read Emacs abbrevs.

```
(defun ivy-abbrev (abbrev-name)
  (interactive
  (list
    (ivy-completing-read "Insert abbrev: " (...get abbrev names here...))))
  (progn
    (abbrev-insert (abbrev-symbol abbrev-name ..appropriate abbrev-table...))))
```

Unfortunately there's nothing in the documentation that makes ...get abbrev names... look do-able:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Abbrevs.html#Abbrevs

Looking in the source at `abbrev--before-point` it looks as though there's a recursive search through `abbrev--active-tables` on each invocation.

Is there a helper method in this abbrev API to make this easier?

Comment: `M-x write-abbrev-file` writes all currently defined abbrevs to a file that you name. Use `quietly-read-abbrev-file` or `read-abbrev-file` to read it. The file whose name is the value of variable `abbrev-file-name` is used by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following,

```
(cl-loop for table in (abbrev--active-tables)
   unless (abbrev-table-empty-p table)
   append (append (delete 0 table) ()))
```

Note that appending nil to a vector is a trick to create a list.